# Cerrar ventanas luego de 25 horas abiertas

Tags: windows, cmd

Tengo un programa específico en Windows 7 que ejecuta cierto proceso vía programador de tareas, cuya salida es una página web simple que se abre cada 30 minutos. De este modo acabo teniendo abiertas muchas ventanas de *Internet Explorer* las cuales producen la saturación del equipo.

Mi intención es que dichas ventanas, se cierren al cabo de *25 horas* (cada ventana individualmente), por lo tanto el comando `cmd /c taskkill /im /f iexplore.exe` no me sirve.

Nota: Intenté resolverlo con el *PID* pero al mirar los procesos, solo tenía 2 procesos de **iexplorer.exe** en funcionamiento a pesar de tener ya varias ventanas abiertas.

Comment: Creo que el principal problema aca es que no queres cerrar ventanas (que es lo que windows sabe que hay) si no pestañas especificas dentro de un programa... No se si eso sera siquiera posible desde una linea de comando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias atacar el problema desde otra perspectiva, si tienes control sobre la pagina web simple, puedes añadir un script que cierre la pagina cuando pase un tiempo determinado.

```
setTimeout( function(){ window.close(); }, 90000000 ); // 90000000 = 25 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas cercano a lo que intentas hacer es `taskkill /IM iexplorer.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq (nombre de la ventana"`, y aunque esto te funcione de alguna manera, tienes que encontrar la manera de hacer que la consola espere 25 horas. No creo que batch te vaya a servir de mucho aquí.